# Finding a Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

> This is the given info:
>   $P(A)=2/5$ ,
>   $P(A \cup B)=3/5$ ,
>   $P(B|A)=1/4$ , 
>   $P(C|B)=1/3$ , 
>   $P(C|A \cap B)=1/2$ ,
>   Find $P(A|B \cap  C)$

I know that $P(A|B \cap C)$ is equivalent to $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ divided by $P(B \cap  C)$.
I was able to calculate $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ by doing $P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A \cap B)$ and I get $1/20$. But I don't know how to calculate $P(B \cap C)$ to calculate $P(A|B \cap C)$. please help.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A) + P(B) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cup B) = P(A)P(B|A) + P(A\cup B).$$

Thus

$$P(B) = P(A)(P(B|A) - 1) + P(A\cup B).$$

And then

$$ P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C|B).$$